# Function to determine if an array is one-dimensional

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, how can I write a function similar to the following, to determine if an array is one-dimensional? (The compiler refuses to compile this because of the `array[i].length` part since `array` hasn't been declared as a nested array.)

```
boolean isOneDimensional(Object[] array)
{
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        if (array[i].length>1) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Or, reconsider your design decision the the number of dimensions of the array should be a runtime property.

Comment: @Raedwald How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You get the `Class` for the entry via [`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) and ask that class if it's an array type via [`isArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray--):</s>

```
boolean isOneDimensional(Object[] array)
{
    // Assuming you want an NPE if `array` is `null`, so not checking
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] != null && array[i].getClass().isArray()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Note the `null` check, just in case.

Nope, my bad, the above gives the wrong result with:

```
isOneDimensional(new String[2][])
```

So basically, there are two kinds of things we could be dealing with: An object that was really created with `Object[]`, and thus could be one-dimensional or multi-dimensional depending on its contents, or an object created with something other than `Object[]`, such as my `new String[2][]` above.

We can detect the first case using my looping version above; but first, we check for the second case using [`array.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--):

```
boolean isOneDimensional(Object[] array) {
    // Assuming you want an NPE if `array` is `null`, so not checking
    if (array.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType() != null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != null && array[i].getClass().isArray()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

We know the first `getComponentType` will come back non-`null` because we're looking at something that's assignment-compatible with `Object[]`, so it definitely has a component type. So we check *that* type's component type, and if it's known to be an array type, we don't need the loop at all.

```
String[]   o1 = new String[2];      // Yes, it's one-dimensional
String[][] o2 = new String[2][];    // No, it isn't
Object[]   o3 = new Object[2];      // It may or may not be, depending on contents
Object[]   o4 = new Object[2];      // It may or may not be, depending on contents

// This makes `o3` multi-dimensional
o3[0] = new Object[0];
System.out.println(isOneDimensional(o1));   // true
System.out.println(isOneDimensional(o2));   // false
System.out.println(isOneDimensional(o3));   // false
System.out.println(isOneDimensional(o4));   // true
```

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder. Now what happens if I use only the first conditional statement (`if (array.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType() != null) return false;`) and omit the loop altogether? Wouldn't that work as well?

Comment: @MohammadSanei: It depends on whether you want `o3` above to return `false` (you need the loop) or `true` (you don't).

Comment: But what if the array is an empty multi-dimensional array? This function will incorrectly return true.

Comment: @ABoschman: How can a multi-dimensional array be one-dimensional? By *definition*, it isn't. But if your preferred interpretation differs, just remove the first check.